# Differences between database/entity framework and in memory lists when mocking in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

I have been doing a lot of unit testing lately with mocking.  The one thing that strikes me as a bit of a problem are the differences between querying against an in memory list (via a mock of my repository) and querying directly against the database via entity framework.

Some of these situations might be:

1. Testing a filter parameter which would be case insensitive against a database but case sensitive 
   against an in memory collection leading to a false fail.
2. Linq statements that might pass against an in memory collection but would fail against entity framework because they arent supported leading to a false pass.

What is the correct way to handle or account for these differences so that there are not false passes or fails in tests?  I really like mocking as it makes things so much quicker and easier to test.  But it seems to me that the only way to get a really accurate test would be to just test against a the entity framework/database environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the unit tests you do you should also create integration tests which run against a real database setup as encountered in production.

I'm not an expert for EF but with NHibernate for example you can create a configuration which points to an in-memory instance of SQLite where you then run your quick tests against (i.e. during a development cycle where you want to get through the test suite as fast as possible). When you want to run your integration tests against a real database you simply change the NHibernate config to point to a real database setup and run the same tests again.

Would be surprising if you could not achieve something similar with EF.

Comment: Would this mean duplicating all of the same tests again (just using the database instead)?  It seems like that would be quite a large bit of work and duplication involved.  At that point why would I mock at all and not just kill two birds with one stone by just writing the test against the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DevMagicFake](http://devmagicfake.codeplex.com/), this framework will fake the DB for you and can also generate data so you can test your application without testing the DB

Answer (score 0):

First and most important is you can define any behavior data within your mock. Second is speed. From unit testing perspective testing speed counts. Database connections are bottleneck most of time so that's why you mock it with tests.
To implement testing properly you need to work on your overall arch first.
For instance to access data layer I use repository pattern sometimes. It's described really good in Eric Evans DDD book.
So let's say if your repository is defined as below
interface [IRepository](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/repository-or-dao-repository.html): IQueryable, ICollection
you can handle linq queries pretty straightforward.
Further reading [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would make my mocks more granular, so that you don't actually query against a larger set in a mock repository.
I typically have setters on my mock repository that I set in each test to control the output of the mocked repository.
This way you don't have to rely on writing queries against a generic mock, and your focus can be on testing the logic in the method under test